# Showing a warning message for blackberry users with a OS older than v6.0

Tags: blackberry

I have developed an application that will support Blackberry OS 6.0 or higher. I want to display warning messages to user's using OS less than 6.0. How can this be achieved. I tried with this code attached. But it is not working.

```
String osVersion = DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion();
String os = "0";
if(!osVersion.equals(""))
    os = osVersion.substring(0, 1);
int osVer = Integer.parseInt(os);
if(osVer < 6){
  //Display a label showing warning to user.
}
else{
  //Continue with application
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way, get a [system cod file version](http://goo.gl/rrmiv) via [CodeModuleManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleManager.html).

For instance get `net_rim_bb_addressbook` version and do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ["Preprocessor Directives"](http://berrytutorials.blogspot.in/2009/11/coding-for-multiple-blackberry-devices.html) to support multiple blackberry devices.